# how to run a script and keep result in a variable in a remote shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

I wrote the following script in a .sh file:

#!/bin/bash

ssh root@192.168.10.10 "a=`ps -ef`;echo $a";

run it and get error lines like "bash: root: command not found...", what's wrong in "a=`ps -ef`;echo $a"?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you simply run the command `ssh root@192.168.10.10 'ps -ef'` from the command line outside the script? Do you have public/private key authentication working to the `root` account on `192.168.10.10`?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
local a
a = $(ssh root@192.168.10.10 "echo ps -ef;")
```

This way, you are executing echo after ssh, and then store the result of this command in a.

Comment: but i need to keep the variable $a inside the script because i need to use it to do more work, why a=\`ps -ef\` can't work?

Comment: because you need to give a full path of the command. See my answer

Comment: i just ran 
ssh root@192.168.10.10 "a=\`ls -l /\`;echo $a";
and get following result:
bash: drwxr-xr-x: command not found...
bash: drwxr-xr-x: command not found...
...
seems part of it works, but not knowing the reason

Comment: First, there are **no spaces** allowed around the `=` in bash. `a=$(ssh root@192.168.10.10 'ls -l /')` will store the output from `ls -l /` in the variable `a` on the local machine using *command substitution*. Just do `printf "a:\n%s\n" "$a"` to confirm.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, i need to keep 'a' in the script, it will be processed in the subsequent remote script, so what i want to run is a huge script such as ssh root@192.168.10.10 "a=\`ps -ef\`;b=\`cat $a | grep ... | sed ...\`;c=\`...$b...\`", so $a need to be kept in the whole remote script, not as a variable in local script

Comment: The problem is the base command. `ssh user@host 'command'`. Where `command` is run on the remote host. You cannot create a variable `a`, `b` or whatever on the remote host that will survive the execution of the `ssh` command. Your alternative to preserve on the remote host is to write to a temp file somewhere on that host. Otherwise, you can save the result of the command in a variable locally and reuse, but not the other way around. Now if you launch a separate script on the remote, e.g. `ssh user@host 'script'` the variables will survive in the script for its life.